# Getting data from C++ model inside delegate

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qml

I have a model on C++ end and a treeview

```
TreeView {
            id: view
            itemDelegate: Rectangle{
                property int indexOfThisDelegate: model.index
                Text {
                text:???
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                }
            }
            model: myModel
            onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log("current index", currentIndex)
            TableViewColumn {
                title: "Name"
                role: "type"
                resizable: true
            }

            onClicked: console.log("clicked", index)
            onDoubleClicked: isExpanded(index) ? collapse(index) : expand(index)
    }
```

How can I get data from my TreeItem? The problem is that *indexOfThisDelegate* is *integer* instead of QModelIndex, so
I would like to have something like

```
Text {
    text:model.getDescription(currentlyPaintedModelIndex)
    font.pixelSize: 14
}
```

or should I have a mapping between integer and tree QModelIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out myself

In the model:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> MenuTreeModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TitleRole] = "Title";
    return roles;
}

// of course it could me more complex with many roles
QVariant MenuTreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }

    MenuTreeItem *item = itemForIndex(index);

    if (role != TitleRole)
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
    QString str = item->data(index.column()).toString();
    return item->data(index.column());
}
```

Our custom tree item (for example):

```
class MenuTreeItem
{
    // item data, contains title
    QList<QVariant> m_itemData; 
};
```

In qml:

```
TreeView {
        id: view
        itemDelegate: Rectangle{
            Text {
            text:model.Title 
                font.pixelSize: 14
            }
        }
        model: myModel
}
```